# Make collector change symbology after registering an object

Tags: arcgis-10.4, arcgis-collector

I use ArcMap 10.4.1 and the latest Arcgis Collector.

I have been using Arcgis Collector for some time now, but I still don't know how to make the symbology of an object change.

What I want, is for a point feature class that is already in the project (lets say houses) to change after it has been inspected. From a red square to a green square. I've been told that this is possible to do, but I can't find a single tutorial for this.

Comment: There are 2 options. Create field preferably with domain holding 2 values and symbolised layer using this field. The same but on the field last edited use r. (editor tracking on). Red color - you, green - all other values

Comment: 1st is manual, 2nd -automatic